# How do I slice an array column-wise within a for loop, adding a new column from the array to a new array for each iteration?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, machine-learning

I'm transcribing an Orthogonal Matching Pursuit algorithm from MATLAB to Python, and I'm having trouble with a specific part of the code.

The Matlab code is:

```matlab
indx=zeros(L,1);
for j=1:1:L
     proj=D'*residual;
     [maxVal,pos]=max(abs(proj));
     pos=pos(1);
     indx(j)=pos;
     a=pinv(D(:,indx(1:j)))*x;
     residual=x-D(:,indx(1:j))*a;
```

What I have for Python so far is:

```
indx = np.zeros([L,], dtype=int)
for j in range(L):
    proj = D.T @ resid
    maxVal, pos = np.amax(np.absolute(proj)), np.argmax(np.absolute(proj), axis = 0)                
    indx[j] = pos               
    d = D[:, indx[j]]
    a = np.linalg.pinv(d) @ x  # take pseudo-inverse of array D and matrix multiply by x
    resid = np.subtract(x, d * a)
```

My problem starts with not being able to create an empty array in Python of undetermined size like you can in MATLAB. For example, I haven't found a satisfactory replication of how MATLAB creates an empty array ( `a = []` ) in Python or Numpy. For right now, I have `a` initialized as `a = []` above the provided code. That's another matter, I think, but in this context a solution to that will help me later on.

To describe what the code is doing in MATLAB a bit, `L = 2`, so if `j = 1` for the first iteration, `D(:,indx(1:j))` will be a 34x1 matrix with column `indx(1)`(which can be any integer from 1 to 80 inclusive) filling the 34 rows. The next iteration will be another column selected from D, which will make `D(:,indx(1:j))` a 34x2 matrix with both columns intact.

I separated slicing into the variable `d` in the python version for clarity. Currently, it overwrites the previously selected column with the new number from `indx` on the second iteration. I really just don't quite know where to go from here. I've tried several different ways of slicing, but none of them work. The closest I've come to getting what I want is setting `indx = np.zeros([L,], dtype=int)` and `d = D[:,indx[j]]`, which gives `indx.shape = (2,)`, but because 0 is an index in Python, the first iteration selects the 0th column of D, so I get the 34x2 array, but with a prematurely selected/added column. If I do `d = D[:, indx[0:j]]`, I get an empty 34x0 array for `d`.

Comment: A typical slice `x:y:i` in python runs as `x`, `x+i`, ... , `y-1`. So you need to write `d = D[:, indx[0:j+1]]` to achieve what you've described.

Comment: @amzon-ex This did it. I know I've tried this, but I may not have tried it with ```indx = np.zeros([L,], dtype=int)```. It was probably set to  ```indx = np.zeros([L,1], dtype=int)``` , which was giving me  ```d.shape = (34, 2, 1)``` . I came here because I've been working on this issue way too long, and I knew I was missing something simple. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may some information missing, but for your first issue, numpy can initialise an empty array using `np.empty` you may be able to explore whether that can help you.

For your second issue I am assuming from what you are writing that you want to get increasing number of columns from the array with each index. If so, you can use `d = D[:, 0:indx+1]` where indx an integer of the row you want